# SSLPeerUnverifiedException:"peer not authenticated" while using groovy's RestClient with ignoreSSLIssues()

Tags: java, ssl, groovy, ssl-certificate

I am writing an integration test for my Rest end point and I have choosen groovy's RestClient. My rest call is on "HTTPS" and I started facing SSL exceptions.
While digging more into this, I was happy to know about ignoreSSLIssues() method (http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/ssl.html). As this is available in 0.7.1 version of HttpBuilder, I upgraded this jar and some dependent jars as well. So with this in place, as per the doc, i was hoping the below code to work -

```
def httpBuilder = new HTTPBuilder('baseurl')
httpBuilder.ignoreSSLIssues()
def resp = httpBuilder.get(path : 'restPath')
println resp
```

But this is still throwing javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue. You also get this deceptive error if you use an outbound proxy and haven't configured the HTTPBuilder class to use it explicitly.

You need to set the setProxy() method of HTTPBuilder. JVM OPTS such as -Dhttp.proxyHost do not seem to be respected by HTTPBuilder for whatever reason. My version looks something like this:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.HEAD

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://www.dev.java.net/' )

http.setProxy("my.proxy.com", 8080, "http")
http.ignoreSSLIssues()

def status = http.request( HEAD ) {
    response.success = { it.status }
}
```